# Basic scene breaks transitioning from three.js v87 to v88 or v89

Tags: three.js

Does anyone know why the following breaks as three.min.js is updated from r87 to r88 or r89?  This is just using fundamentals from three.js-related training webistes.  With r87 or earlier, a cube is displayed.  With r88 or r89, there's just a black canvas.  I have tried this with Chrome, Firefox, & IE.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Demo</title>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="three.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var renderer = null, scene = null, camera = null;

    function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);     
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("webglcanvas");

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true});
        renderer.setSize(canvas.width, canvas.height);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 400);
        camera.position.set(60, 100, 100);
        scene.add(camera);

        camera.lookAt({"x": 50.0, "y": 50.0, "z": 50.0});

        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffff00);
        light.position.set(50, 50, 50);
        scene.add(light);

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);
        var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);

        render();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <canvas id="webglcanvas" width="480" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not valid three.js code, and never has been valid three.js code:

```
camera.lookAt( { "x": 50.0, "y": 50.0, "z": 50.0 } );
```

Use

```
camera.lookAt( 50, 50, 50 );
```

or

```
camera.lookAt( myVector3 );
```

three.js r.90

Comment: Thanks - I changed that line, and then got the expected results with r88 and r89.  (I will try the new r90 soon).